# On mouseover change auto to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and i want the mouseover to change the variable auto from true to false.

```
if ($featuredArea.length) {
    $featuredArea.et_switcher({
    useArrows: true <?php if (get_option($shortname.'_slider_auto') == 'on') { ?>,
            auto: true,
            autoSpeed: <?php echo(get_option($shortname.'_slider_autospeed')); ?>
            <?php }; ?> 

            });
        };

        $("div.slide").mouseover(function(){
            $featuredArea.et_switcher({
            auto: false
            });
         });
```

The last part is where I am trying to do that where it stars with div.slide. However it is not working.

Comment: This would vary by plugin, which plugin are you using?

Comment: I believe the plugin is superfish.js

Comment: You can see it in action here flamingoroadchurch.com.previewdns.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it work would be to change the variable name of `auto` to `window.auto`. That way you're positive that the value is being updated everything since it's superglobal. This, however, isn't very good practice; merely a quick fix.